How to improve response time of Phi-3-medium-128k serverless API?
I have deployed the Phi-3-medium-128k model using Azure AI Studio (serverless deployment). I am using the v1/chat/completions API to get chat completions and I am streaming the response. The time to first token is quite high, ~15 secs for an average input length of 3000 tokens. These are some of the config parameters I am using:
"temperature": 0.0, "max_tokens": 1000, "top_p": 1.0
Is the latency supposed to be this high? How can I improve it?
This is the Python function I am using to call Phi-3 API:
def get_phi3_response(sys_prompt, user_prompt, stream=True):
    messages = format_message_for_llm(sys_prompt, user_prompt)
    data = {
        "model": "phi3-medium-128k",
        "temperature": 0.0,
        "max_tokens": 1000,
        "top_p": 1.0,
        "messages": messages,
        "stream": stream,
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + PHI3_API_KEY,
    }
    response = {}
    try:
        res = requests.post(PHI3_API_URL, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        response = res
    except Exception as e:
        response = {}
        print("Error in get_phi3_response: " + str(e))
    return response

Once I make the call, I am consuming the response using SSE-Client in this function:
response = get_phi3_response(SYS_PROMPT, 'What is photosynthesis', True) 
sseClient = SSEClient(response)
for event in sseClient.events():
    print('event_data', event.data)

I have tried reducing the input length, which did not make much difference.

Can you share your code in the question?

@DasariKamali added my code to the question
